# Referencing node modules in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

*I'm a recent refugee from the Flex/Actionscript/AIR world and am loving working with Electron, Node and beginning to understand some of the conventions of working with Javascript.*

**Question:** I've been using the method below to reference modules which I have installed in a project. It works but I have the suspicion that I am "doing it wrong" – mostly because after the simplicity of the "npm install ..." method, I then have to dig through the contents of `node_modules`, find what I just installed and then construct the path to it.

What am I missing here?

```
<script src="../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electron is fully supported with node, which includes require as it's dependency manager.
You can use the `require` statement to include modules.
In a js file..

```
var videojs = require('videojs')
```

or in an HTML file

```
<script>
    require('videojs')
</script>
```

The [Electron FAQ](http://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron) might answer some other questions.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined